# DDMS android

Tags: android

Можно ли эмулировать на DDMS подключение наушников?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RTFM](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html):

> The functional limitations of the
> emulator include:
>
> No support for device-attached headphones

Comment: спасибо,понял